# Javascript persistent access to local files across browser instances/page refreshes

Tags: javascript, html, persistent-storage

I'm looking for a way to allow the user to select a file using the standard  element, and allow the browser to access that file persistently across page refreshes and/or browser instances.

Scenario:

- We have a web app that we want to license to users.
- We want to send the user a license file that they save to their local computer.
- The first time they access our web app, they use an  field to select the local license file on their computer
- Each subsequent time they access the app (whether they close the browser, reboot the machine, etc), it can read the license file directly, without needing the user to re-select the file.

We don't want to use localStorage to store the entire file, as the file's max size is not limited and may grow outside the size limits of localStorage.

I have partially succeeded:  As long as the original browser tab is open, any other browser instance or tab can access the file and read it.  However, if the original tab is closed, the local file URL is destroyed.

Here's how I did this part:

- When user selects a file from  field, use the window.createObjectURL() function to create an object URL for the selected file.
- Save this object URL in localStorage

Whenever another browser instance/tab accesses this URL, it can load the file using the XHR object and the FileReader object.  Here's the bit of code:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
console.log("Reading URL: " + localStorage.savedFile);
xhr.open('GET', localStorage.savedFile, true);
xhr.responseType = 'blob';
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(e)
{
    if (xhr.readyState == 4)
    {
        var myBlob = this.response;
        console.log(myBlob);
        var f = new FileReader();
        f.onload = function(e) { console.log(e); alert("Data read: " + e.target.result); };
        f.readAsText(myBlob);

    }
};
xhr.send();
```

As you can see, the xhr object gets a blob back, and can send this directly to the FileReader object to read the data.

This works perfectly as long as the original tab (the one where they selected the file) is open.  But apparently the URLs generated by createObjectURL() are destroyed upon close of the tab (which makes sense from a garbage collection standpoint).

Can anyone think of a way to persist the URL across instances/tabs without needing the original tab to be kept open, and to allow access to the same local file without the user needing to manually select it every time they access the app?

Comment: Also, I'm aware of the FileSystem API (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebGuide/API/File_System#Browser_Compatibility) but it looks like it's dead (http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-webapps/2014AprJun/0010.html), and unpredictable across browsers.

Comment: did you find a solution eventually?

Comment: No, unfortunately not. Did you?

Comment: I can see multiple uses for this.  It would be nice to have a persistent 'object' that could be referenced between browser sessions/executions that points to a filesystem object...

Comment: Same here. Currently investigating if I could use good old-fashioned Flash bridge in my particular scenario (but this is definitely not an option in general).

Comment: I'd be interested in your use-case also if you are able to share.

Answer (score -1):

This is very similar to a single sign on, but with additional validation.

This is one solution:

- Create a hash of the license (or encrypt a "licence key", some unique identifier of the license)
- Store the hash in a cookie or local storage
- Also pass the hash to the server and save the mapping between hash and the client, and date/time last accessed
- Every time the user logs in, validate the cookie or local storage for the presence of the hash entry and the validity of the hash. You may also want to perform additional validations list last used, number of clients etc.

Comment: So you can't think of any way to directly access the actual *file* persistently?  that's the goal.